# Is $x=0$, in $x^2(x^2 + 4) = 0$, unique root or repeated?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In $x^2(x^2+4) = 0$, $x^2 = 0$ and $x = 0$, is that a one solution or two? Because if you square root both sides you get $x = \pm 0$ so is it $+0$ and $-0$ or just $0$?

Comment: Note that for a polynomial $p(x)$, $a$ is a repeated root (with order at least 2) if and only if $p(a)=p'(a)=0$. Here is the case for 0, so it's repeated root.

Answer (score 2):

The multiplicity of the solution is two: since the solutions $x=-2i$ and $x=2i$ have multiplicity 1 and the polynomial is of multiplicity 4 that leaves $x=0$ with multiplicity 2(by the [fundamental theorem of algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra)). You can see the multiplicity is even in a graph because the graph "bounces back at the point "$x=0$" in other words it doesn't cross the x-axis.

Answer (score 1):

When looking at the roots of polynomials, you count roots with multiplicity. This lets us say that a degree $n$ polynomial has $n$ roots, counting multiplicity. So, in your case the polynomial $x^2(x^2+4)$ has a double root at zero.

The distinction isn't between $+0$ and $-0$, as you indicate those are both just equal to zero. One reason that we count roots with multiplicity is that this tells us how much we can divide without breaking anything. In this case we can divide your polynomial by $x^2$ and the resulting function is defined at zero.

Comment: so for x^2 it's just x=0 and not x= +-0 , correct?

Comment: Correct! Strictly speaking I suppose there's nothing wrong with writing $\pm 0$, this just means $+0$ and $-0$, but $+0$ and $-0$ happen to both be equal to $0$.

Comment: Because I am solving a differential equation problem and I need to make sure to if the roots are repeated, complex, or unique in order to use the general solution equations. Like for example, if it is truly just 0, then it would be y=c1e^0 but if +-0 then it would be y=c1e^(-0) + c1e^(+0).

Comment: Well, this is a repeated root, or a root of multiplicity two, but it's incorrect to draw some sort of distinction between $+0$ and $-0$. It's hard to help you with whatever your problem in differential equations is without knowing what it is, but you should notice that if you said that the solution was $y=c_1e^{+0}+c_1e^{-0}$ this is just the same as $y=c_1+c_1$.